# MacOS system properties reference (mentioned in .plist files)

Tags: macos, plist

Is there a reference of MacOS system properties that we can change through Intune policies? For example, minimum Password length requirement, password lifetime, etc.

I wonder what other system properties are available for configuration. This is like Group policies in Windows, but in windows there is a tool that shows all available properties, is there such thing in Mac? Or may be some sort of reference documentation?  I know that such properties are stored in `.plist` files `com.apple.*.plist`.

Comment: Think we had the question before but couldn’t find it so far. Unfortunately there is no central repository of all properties manageable via plist files.

Answer (score 4):

## No Definitive Defaults Documentation

Unfortunately there is no definitive *defaults* documentation from Apple. The contents of preference files are considered implementation specific and are not expected to be changed by third party tools or directly by users.

### Defaults

These settings are often called **Defaults**, after the macOS command line tool that can read and write them, [`defaults`](https://dssw.co.uk/reference/defaults).

An attempt to collect and document many of these defaults was made as part of the [macOS Defaults project](https://github.com/kevinSuttle/macOS-Defaults):

> #### macOS Defaults
>
> A place to centralize the great work @mathiasbynens did gathering and fostering a community around finding and documenting macOS default configuration from the command-line.

Comment: Thanks! Very usefull command.

Answer (score 1):

## MDM – Profile-Specific Payload Keys

It wasn't easy, but I found the [Device Management – Profile-Specific Payload Keys](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/profile-specific_payload_keys) reference on the Apple site:

> Deploying a mobile device management (MDM) solution allows administrators to securely and remotely configure enrolled devices.
>
> …
>
> In addition to the standard payload keys (described in [Define a Profile](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/configuring_multiple_devices_using_profiles?language=objc#3234127)) each payload can contain keys specific to a payload type. > These payload specific keys are described in detail, below.

I hope it will be useful.

Comment: This is a bit of link-only answer. I might be worth quoting the part of the document that answers your question.

Comment: @Greeonline We usually don't duplicate Apple's documentation on AD itself. OTOH I would love to see an edit which show how the information on that page can be used to solve the problem described in the question (changing password rules) and which explains the link between MDM payload keys and defaults/plist entries.